# Create Button is Not Visible - Using React and Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am developing a project using React and Tailwind CSS. I'm trying to add a "Create" button, but it is not visible. I need your help to resolve this issue.

Here are my relevant components:

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Modal from './components/Modal';
import GlobalContext from './context/GlobalContext';

function App() {
  const { showEventModal } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {showEventModal && <Modal />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**GlobalContext.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const GlobalContext = React.createContext({
  showEventModal: false,
  setShowEventModal: () => {},
});

export default GlobalContext;
```

**ContextWrapper.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GlobalContext from './GlobalContext';

export default function ContextWrapper(props) {
  const [showEventModal, setShowEventModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        showEventModal,
        setShowEventModal,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Modal.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import GlobalContext from '../context/GlobalContext';

export default function Modal() {
  const { setShowEventModal } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div className='fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center'>
      <form className='bg-white rounded-lg w-1/2'>
        <header className='bg-blue-300 px-4 py-4 flex justify-between items-center'>
          <div>
            <p className='ml-3 font-semibold text-gray-600'>Create Report</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowEventModal(false)} className='flex justify-end'>
              <span className="material-icons-outlined text-gray-400 mr-1">close</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </header>
        {/* Form content */}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CreateButton.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import GlobalContext from '../context/GlobalContext';

export default function CreateButton() {
  const { setShowEventModal } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start px-5 py-10'>
      <button onClick={() => setShowEventModal(true)} className='text-white bg-slate-400 hover:bg-slate-700 rounded focus:outline-none font-medium px-4 py-2 text-center mr-1'>
        Create
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have added the "Create" button in the CreateButton component, but it is not visible. How can I resolve this issue? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You have not used `CreateButton` component anywhere in your app.

Comment: yes i am stupid. thank you

Answer (score 0):

"I forgot to add

```
<React.StrictMode>
 <ContextWrapper><App/></ContextWrapper>
</React.StrictMode>"
```

to index.js and I forgot to import CreateButton in app.js."